# Azure Server Load Balancing

Tags: azure, load, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer, appserver

If we had hosted our server on Azure will be scale according to the load or do we need to have multiple app server and have a load balance?

Comment: I think you forgot to add all the details of what you mean with "server". if it's just a plain virtual machine, it will not scale automatically.

Comment: Right, Virtual machines are different from an App Service. If you mean that you have an API and that's your server, then they can load balance automatically if they are setup for auto scaling. If you need virtual machines, then you need to connect a load balancer to more than one identical VMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you host your server on a plain virtual machine, It will not be auto-scale action, but you can host it on the [virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview) for high availability and application resiliency and it will allow your application to automatically scale as resource demand changes.

You also could put an [Azure load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) in front of your backend standard VMs/VM scale sets/availability set to scale your applications and create high availability for your services.

Moreover, you could directly choose to use PAAS instead of IAAS service on Azure, so you do not worry more about the underlying infrastructure. [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) enables you to build and host web apps, mobile back ends, and RESTful APIs in the programming language of your choice without managing infrastructure. It offers auto-scaling and high availability, supports both Windows and Linux, and enables automated deployments from GitHub, Azure DevOps, or any Git repo.

Hope this could help you.